# SSH works from local environment to sftp, but failes with "Authentication (publickey) failed" on GAE

Tags: python, google-app-engine, ssh

I'm working on a feature to upload a file to an sftp from a python (flask) app.
The code below works locally on windows machine and authenticates successfully:

```
privkey = io.StringIO("private_key_in_string")
pkey = paramiko.RSAKey.from_private_key(privkey)
ssh = paramiko.SSHClient()
ssh.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())
ssh.connect("sftp.hostname.com",port=12345, username=username, pkey=pkey)
conn = ssh.open_sftp()
```

but when i upload it to my GAE flex instance, i get the following error with the exact same code:

```
Connected (version 2.0, client dropbear)
Authentication (publickey) failed.
```

Does Anyone have any idea what can help here?

Comment: I suspect that GAE flex blocks certain ports.

Comment: You should use Service Account and Service Account key. Read more on them [here](https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/understanding-service-accounts) and [here](https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/reference/rest/v1/projects.serviceAccounts.keys). You may also try connecting to that instance by running: `gcloud app instances ssh`. Let me know what you think.

Comment: it turned out there is a known issue in the paramiko and the solution was to add warnings.filterwarnings(action='ignore',module='.*')

Answer (score 1):

It turned out there is a known issue in the `paramiko` and the solution was to add:

```py
warnings.filterwarnings(action='ignore',module='.*')
```